# C# Azure EventHub connection exception

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-eventhub

Hy Guys,
i have a problem, unfortunately I'm trying to connect to the Azure EventHub but I always get an exception like:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt
> failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
> period of time, or established connection failed because connected
> host has failed to respond.    at
> Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TransportStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult)    at
> Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TransportStream.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.b__1(IAsyncResult
> a)    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
> requiresSynchronization)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.g__InternalFillHandshakeBufferAsync|189_0[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter
> adap, ValueTask`1 task, Int32 minSize)    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskToApm.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TlsTransport.HandleOpenComplete(IAsyncResult result, Boolean syncComplete) --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.ExceptionDispatcher.Throw(Exception exception)    at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)    at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpObject.OpenAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)    at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpObject.EndOpen(IAsyncResult result)    at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TlsTransportInitiator.HandleTransportOpened(IAsyncResult result)    at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.TlsTransportInitiator.OnTransportOpened(IAsyncResult result) --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.ExceptionDispatcher.Throw(Exception exception)    at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)    at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.AmqpTransportInitiator.ConnectAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)    at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.AmqpTransportInitiator.<>c.<ConnectAsync>b__17_1(IAsyncResult r)    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
> iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpConnectionScope.CreateAndOpenConnectionAsync(Version amqpVersion, Uri serviceEndpoint, Uri connectionEndpoint, EventHubsTransportType transportType, IWebProxy proxy, Int32 sendBufferSizeBytes, Int32 receiveBufferSizeBytes, RemoteCertificateValidationCallback certificateValidationCallback, String scopeIdentifier, TimeSpan timeout)    at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.OnCreateAsync(TimeSpan
> timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpConnectionScope.OpenManagementLinkAsync(TimeSpan
> operationTimeout, TimeSpan linkTimeout, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.OnCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpClient.GetPropertiesAsync(EventHubsRetryPolicy
> retryPolicy, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpClient.GetPropertiesAsync(EventHubsRetryPolicy
> retryPolicy, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.EventHubConnection.GetPropertiesAsync(EventHubsRetryPolicy
> retryPolicy, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.EventHubConnection.GetPartitionIdsAsync(EventHubsRetryPolicy
> retryPolicy, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Consumer.EventHubConsumerClient.GetPartitionIdsAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at Program.Main() in
> C:\Users\f.daquila\RiderProjects\AuditLogRecevierSample\AuditLogRecevierSample\Program.cs:line
> 20    at Program.Main() in
> C:\Users\f.daquila\RiderProjects\AuditLogRecevierSample\AuditLogRecevierSample\Program.cs:line
> 41

The code with which I try to make the call is this:

```
class Program
{
    private const string eventHubConnectionString = "<CONNECTION STRING>";
    private const string consumerGroup = "<GROUP NAME>";
    
    
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        try
        {
            await using var consumer = new EventHubConsumerClient(consumerGroup, new EventHubConnection(eventHubConnectionString));
            var startingPosition = EventPosition.Earliest;

            var partitionIds = await consumer.GetPartitionIdsAsync();

            if (partitionIds is not null && partitionIds.Any())
            {
                var partitionId = partitionIds.First();
                using var cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                cancellationSource.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45));

                await foreach (var receivedEvent in consumer.ReadEventsFromPartitionAsync(partitionId, startingPosition, cancellationSource.Token))
                {
                    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedEvent.Data.Body.ToArray());

                    Console.WriteLine(body);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to see if there were any problems with the network using powershell by testing the connection like this:

[image]

and everything seems to be ok.
What am I doing wrong? Why can't I connect?

A thousand thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common connection issue for persistent timeouts is that the ports needed for AMQP over TCP (5671/5672) are not open.  This is often turns out to be the root cause even when `Test-NetConnection` succeeds.

Changing the transport to AMQP over WebSockets usually helps, as it will use port 443 and may be routed through a proxy, if needed.  The transport can be specified using the `EventHubConsumerClientOptions` when creating your consumer:

```cs
var options = new EventHubConsumerClientOptions();
options.ConnectionOptions.TransportType = EventHubsTransportType.AmqpWebSockets;

await using var consumer = new EventHubConsumerClient(
    "<< CONSUMER GROUP >>",
    "<< CONNECTION STRING >>",
    "<< EVENT HUB NAME >>",
    options);
```

If that doesn't resolve the issue, I'd suggest taking a look at the [Event Hubs troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#connectivity-issues) for further steps.

A couple of other notable things about your snippet:

- There's no reason to explicitly create an `EventHubConnection` unless you're creating multiple clients and would like to force them to share a single connection.
- The return from `GetPartitionIdsAsync` will never be `null` and will always have at least one member.  It is not possible to create an Event Hub with no partitions.
- There's no need to explicitly decode the bytes for an event body.  Using `receivedEvent.Data.EventBody.ToString()` would give you the same result.
- The `EventData.Body` property is deprecated and is hidden; it exists only for backwards compatibility.  We recommend using `EventBody` which provides additional functionality for working with binary data.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestions. Being the consumer in a corporate network and behind a reverse proxy, I believe that you have concentrated the problem right. A thousand thanks